postgresql union and jsonb_build_object
I have been looking around and facing an issue that I don't see how to solve
Many thanks, and after completly rewritten my query
WITH cte1 as (
   SELECT distinct jsonb_build_object( 
       select jsonb_build_object('active',false, 'descriptionPersonne', 
           (select  jsonb_build_object('a','a'))) as personne) 
,cte2 as (
    select jsonb_build_object('active',false,'descriptionCompany',
       (select  jsonb_build_object('a','a'))) as company)

SELECT distinct jsonb_build_object('personne',personne)
    ,jsonb_build_object('company',company) from cte, cte2

my results are expected to look like this
{"entity": [
{"company": {"descriptionCompany": {"a": "c1"}, "active": false}}, 
{"personne": {"descriptionPersonne": {"a": "p1"}, "active": false}}
{"personne": {"descriptionPersonne": {"a": "P2"}, "active": false}}
]}


instead the look like this :



jsonb_build_objet
jsonb_build_objet




p1
c1


p2
c1



I have tried many other options like having a with statement, or json_build_array

Your issue is that the union takes its column names from the first select in the union.

Your problem is that t is a tuple type with a single column named personne - that's what the union returns. It can't have different columns for different rows. You need to build the objects per query.

Many thanks, so I have completly rewritten my query : `WITH cte1 as (SELECT distinct jsonb_build_object(
select jsonb_build_object(
'active',false
,'descriptionPersonne', (select  jsonb_build_object('a','a'))
) as personne)
,cte2 as (   select jsonb_build_object(
'active',false
,'descriptionCompany', (select  jsonb_build_object('a','a'))
) as company)
SELECT distinct jsonb_build_object('personne',personne),jsonb_build_object('company',company)   from cte, cte2` but doesn't get the expected results

Basically I came up with the following solution to be able to handle null response :
SELECT jsonb_build_object('mandate',(select (case when count (cte2.company2) = 0 then 
(select CONCAT('[',STRING_AGG(cte.personne2 #>> '{}',', '),']') from cte)
else
(select CONCAT('[',
STRING_AGG(cte.personne2 #>> '{}',', ')
,','
,STRING_AGG(cte2.company2  #>> '{}',', '),']' ) from cte,cte2)
end)
from cte,cte2   )::json)

